# How can I get a certain string out of my log?

Tags: groovy

I need to get a certain string out of my log and show it but I am not sure how to do it. Here is my code

```
<%if(build.result==Result.OK) 
{ 
build.getLog(100).each() 
{ 
line -> %>
${line}
<%  } %>
```

Now the string that shows up is something like this (the last part with the name will change):

```
 09:19:52 Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/2.0.4.121106.zip
```

I would like to get that http string out but I dont know how. Could someone please advice me?

Answer (score 0):

```
line.substring(line.indexOf("http://"))
```

Comment: does not work at all. Get errors. Does this really work for groovy?

Comment: Yes, it works. See http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/803001 : click on Execute script, and see the output. If at least you tols us which error you get, and which code ou're trying to execute.

Comment: The `line.substring(line.indexOf("http://"))` must replace `line` in `${line}`, and not in `line ->`.